# Makefile targets autocomplete when using wild card targets

Tags: linux, makefile

```
> ls
abcd.config  efgh.config  ijkl.config
```

Makefile:

```
%_defconfig: %.config
    @echo "Some commands i want to run on %.config"
```

What i want is autosuggestion (tab completion) for

```
abcd_defconfig 
efgh_defconfig
ijkl_defconfig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly declare the targets for which you want auto completion? For instance with the `wildcard` and `patsubst` functions and a static pattern rule instead of a pattern rule:

```makefile
configs     := $(wildcard *.config)
defconfigs  := $(patsubst %.config,%_defconfig,$(configs))

$(defconfigs): %_defconfig: %.config
    @echo "Some commands i want to run on $<"
```

Comment: Wow.. that runs like butter. 
Thanks @Renaud Pacalet